# Extension options menu?

Tags: crossrider

When I right click on my browser button there is a grayed out "Options" option. When I click on this option for other extensions, a simple page is shown that allows you to change settings for the extension.

Is there any way to enable the Options menu for a CrossRider extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the Crossrider browser action button does not support the **Options** feature when right-clicking on the button. It's probably not a feature that can be supported cross browser, however, I have forwarded it to the product team as a suggestion for Chrome.

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]